ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'gan_model'
I encountered an error while trying to build a GAN model. Here's the code snippet where the error occurs:
code snippet
np.random.seed(SEED)
for epoch in range(10):
    for batch in tqdm(range(STEPS_PER_EPOCH)):

        # Generate fake images
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_DIM))
        fake_X = generator.predict(noise)

        # Select a random batch of real images
        idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], size=BATCH_SIZE)
        real_X = X_train[idx]

        # Reshape fake images to match the shape of real images
        fake_X_reshaped = np.transpose(fake_X, axes=(0, 2, 1, 3))

        # Concatenate real and fake images into a single batch
        X = np.concatenate((real_X, fake_X_reshaped))

        # Create labels for the discriminator
        disc_y = np.zeros(2 * BATCH_SIZE)
        disc_y[:BATCH_SIZE] = 1

        # Train the discriminator on the batch
        d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(X, disc_y)
        
        # Generate new noise for the generator
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_DIM))

        # Create labels for the generator (trick the discriminator)
        y_gen = np.ones(BATCH_SIZE)

        # Train the generator to fool the discriminator
        g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(noise, y_gen)

    print(f"EPOCH: {epoch + 1} Generator Loss: {g_loss:.4f} Discriminator Loss: {d_loss:.4f}")
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(10, NOISE_DIM))
    sample_images(noise, (2, 5))

error message
 0%|                                                                                         | 0/3750 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 16 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x0000023093B2E480> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 587ms/step
  0%|                                                                                         | 0/3750 [00:02<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[138], line 33
     30     y_gen = np.ones(BATCH_SIZE)
     32     # Train the generator to fool the discriminator
---> 33     g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(noise, y_gen)
     35 print(f"EPOCH: {epoch + 1} Generator Loss: {g_loss:.4f} Discriminator Loss: {d_loss:.4f}")
     36 noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(10, NOISE_DIM))

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py:2787, in Model.train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics, return_dict)
   2783     iterator = data_adapter.single_batch_iterator(
   2784         self.distribute_strategy, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight
   2785     )
   2786     self.train_function = self.make_train_function()
-> 2787     logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   2789 logs = tf_utils.sync_to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   2790 if return_dict:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb

File C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file_1d1u69b.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py:1384, in Model.make_train_function.<locals>.step_function(model, iterator)
   1380     run_step = tf.function(
   1381         run_step, jit_compile=True, reduce_retracing=True
   1382     )
   1383 data = next(iterator)
-> 1384 outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
   1385 outputs = reduce_per_replica(
   1386     outputs,
   1387     self.distribute_strategy,
   1388     reduction=self.distribute_reduction_method,
   1389 )
   1390 return outputs

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py:1373, in Model.make_train_function.<locals>.step_function.<locals>.run_step(data)
   1372 def run_step(data):
-> 1373     outputs = model.train_step(data)
   1374     # Ensure counter is updated only if `train_step` succeeds.
   1375     with tf.control_dependencies(_minimum_control_deps(outputs)):

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py:1150, in Model.train_step(self, data)
   1148 # Run forward pass.
   1149 with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
-> 1150     y_pred = self(x, training=True)
   1151     loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
   1152 self._validate_target_and_loss(y, loss)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py:298, in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    296 if spec_dim is not None and dim is not None:
    297     if spec_dim != dim:
--> 298         raise ValueError(
    299             f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '
    300             "incompatible with the layer: "
    301             f"expected shape={spec.shape}, "
    302             f"found shape={display_shape(x.shape)}"
    303         )

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Mohamed Walid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Mohamed Walid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Mohamed Walid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Mohamed Walid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1150, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\Mohamed Walid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\Mohamed Walid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'gan_model' (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "discriminator" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 208, 176, 1), found shape=(4, 176, 208, 1)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'gan_model' (type Functional):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 100), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None


I'm attempting to train a Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) model. The goal is to generate fake images using the generator model and then train the discriminator to distinguish between real and fake images. Here's a brief overview of the process:
Generating fake images using the generator model.
Selecting a random batch of real images from the dataset.
Concatenating real and fake images into a single batch.
Creating labels for the discriminator.
Training the discriminator on the batch.
Generating new noise for the generator.
Creating labels for the generator to fool the discriminator.
Training the generator.
Additional Information:
The code is implemented in Python using Keras.
I'm using a specific architecture for the generator and discriminator models.
I've checked the shapes of input data and they seem to be correct.
The error occurs during the training loop, specifically when calling gan.train_on_batch(noise, y_gen).
Any insights into what might be causing this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The error is very clear,  you just need to flip the image dimensions.

can you help me in this it gave the same error
